# C# axWindowsMediaPlayer Change Video Position with Custom Trackbar

Tags: c#, winforms, playback, trackbar, axwindowsmediaplayer

I have a `axWindowsMediaPlayer` on WinForm with `uiMode=none`. I am using my custom controls to handle playback. I am using [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24290709) to associate a `trackBar` with `axWindowsMediaPlayer`.

I want to change the video position (jump to specific time) when the user scrolls the `trackBar`, just like windows media player.

```
private void trackBar_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (axWindowsMediaPlayer.playState == WMPLib.WMPPlayState.wmppsPlaying)
    {
        axWindowsMediaPlayer.Ctlcontrols.currentPosition = trackBar.Value;
    }
}
```

This is not working. I have checked many Stackoverflow answers including [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4309397), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5591140), and the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/wmp/wmplibiwmpcontrols-iwmpcontrols-currentposition--vb-and-c) but none is working.

I have two objectives:

1. When playing media, the `trackBar` should show the current position of the media file being played. This is working fine.
2. When the user scrolls the `trackBar`, the media player should change the video current position based on the `trackBar` value. This is not working.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: When it is the user that moves the trackbar thumb (use a bool variable to see the difference) then you need to pause playback first.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue. The problem was not with the media player, the problem was with the media files being played with the `axWindowsMediaPlayer`.

`axWindowsMediaPlayer` plays the files such as MKV fine, but if the proper codecs are not installed, the `Ctlcontrols` mainly the Trackbar does not work from code or UI. With natively supported formats, this code works perfectly fine.

```
private void trackBar_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (axWindowsMediaPlayer.playState == WMPLib.WMPPlayState.wmppsPlaying)
        axWindowsMediaPlayer.Ctlcontrols.currentPosition = trackBar.Value;      
}
```

For media files not natively supported, their codecs need to be installed. For details of supported file formats, see this KB article [File types supported by Windows Media Player](http://File%20types%20supported%20by%20Windows%20Media%20Player)